Animate dropdown arrow to transform 180 degrees when activated
How can I make the arrow of my dropdown rotate once opened?
I have tried using different methods, including using methods like .bd-aside .btn[aria-expanded="true"]::before {transform: rotate(90deg);}, using ::after and ::before elements, however those did not work.
Dropdown Inactive:

Dropdown Active:

I would like the arrow to smoothly rotate 180 degrees over 0.15 seconds.


// Navbar Dropdown
$(".ctx-dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
    $(this).next(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle(600);
});
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap");
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css");

/*navbar begin*/
.navbar {
    height: 60px;
}

.navbar-brand {
    --bs-navbar-brand-padding-y: 0px;
    --bs-navbar-brand-margin-end: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand-text {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, red, magenta, magenta, lime);
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-size: 300% 100%;
    background-position: left center;
    transition: background 0.15s linear;
}

.navbar-brand:hover .navbar-brand-text {
    background-position: 100% center;
}

.navbar-brand:focus {
    outline: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
    .navbar-brand > .navbar-brand-text {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 370px) {
    .navbar-brand {
        display: none;
    }
}

.navbar-toggler {
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    padding: 5px 10px !important;
    transition: border-color 0.15s linear !important;
}

.navbar-toggler:hover {
    border-color: #ff0000;
}

.navbar-toggler:focus {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7) !important;
}

.nav-link {
    color: #808080;
    transition: color linear 0.15s;
}

.nav-link:hover {
    color: #ff00ff;
}

.nav-link:focus {
    color: #ff00ff;
}
/*navbar end*/

/*dropdown begin*/
.dropdown-menu {
    background: #111;
    --bs-dropdown-min-width: 100px;
    --bs-dropdown-border-radius: 10px;
    --bs-dropdown-border-width: 2px;
    --bs-dropdown-border-color: #ff0000;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
    color: #808080;
    transition: color linear 0.15s;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
    color: #ff00ff;
    background-color: #111;
}

.dropdown-menu a:focus {
    color: #ff00ff;
    background-color: #111;
}

.dropdown-divider {
    border-top: 1px solid #252424;
}

.dropdown-item:active {
    background: #111 !important;
}

.dropdown-item:focus {
    background-color: #111;
    color: #ff00ff !important;
}

.bi-chevron-up {
    display: inline-block;
}

/*dropdown end*/
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>Cratex Studios</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65"
            crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <script
            src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css"
            integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU"
            crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico" />
        <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false">
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="navbar">
                <div class="container-fluid justify-content-between">
                    <button
                        class="navbar-toggler"
                        type="button"
                        data-bs-toggle="offcanvas"
                        data-bs-target="#leftMainNav"
                        aria-controls="leftMainNav"
                        aria-label="Toggle left navigation">
                        <i class="bi bi-list"></i>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
                        <img style="width: 30px" src="assets/images/logo-l.png" />
                        <span class="navbar-brand-text">Cratex Studios</span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="d-flex" style="width: 250px">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link ctx-dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false"
                                    >Company <i class="bi bi-chevron-up"></i
                                ></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu position-absolute" style="top: 55px; width: 110px">
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
                                    <li>
                                        <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/mission.php">Mission</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/partners.php">Partners</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/affiliates.php">Affiliates</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/legal.php">Legal Info</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/support.php">Support</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/team.php">Our Team</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            class="btn btn-menu mt-1 ms-2 me-2"
                            data-bs-toggle="modal"
                            data-bs-target="#signupModal">
                            Sign Up
                        </button>
                        <button
                            class="navbar-toggler"
                            type="button"
                            data-bs-toggle="offcanvas"
                            data-bs-target="#rightMainNav"
                            aria-controls="rightMainNav"
                            aria-label="Toggle right navigation">
                            <i class="bi bi-list"></i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end bg-dark" tabindex="-1" id="rightMainNav" aria-labelledby="rightMainNav">
                        <div class="offcanvas-header">
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                class="justify-content-end offcanvas-close-btn"
                                data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"
                                aria-label="Close">
                                <i class="bi bi-x-circle"></i>
                            </button>
                            <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="rightMainNavLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="offcanvas-body justify-content-end">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav text-end">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link active-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start bg-dark" tabindex="-1" id="leftMainNav" aria-labelledby="leftMainNav">
                        <div class="offcanvas-header">
                            <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="leftMainNavLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
                            <button
                                type="button"
                                class="btn-close btn-close-white"
                                data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"
                                aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="offcanvas-body">
                            <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link active-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a
                                        type="button"
                                        class="btn d-inline-flex align-items-center border-0 nav-link"
                                        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                                        aria-expanded="true"
                                        data-bs-target="#components-collapse"
                                        aria-controls="components-collapse">
                                        Components
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="list-unstyled ps-3 collapse" id="components-collapse">
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#accordion"
                                                >Accordion</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#alerts">Alerts</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#badge">Badge</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#breadcrumb"
                                                >Breadcrumb</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#buttons"
                                                >Buttons</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#button-group"
                                                >Button group</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#card">Card</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#carousel"
                                                >Carousel</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#dropdowns"
                                                >Dropdowns</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#list-group"
                                                >List group</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#modal">Modal</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#navs">Navs</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#navbar">Navbar</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#pagination"
                                                >Pagination</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#popovers"
                                                >Popovers</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#progress"
                                                >Progress</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#scrollspy"
                                                >Scrollspy</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#spinners"
                                                >Spinners</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#toasts">Toasts</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#tooltips"
                                                >Tooltips</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>



I have included a snippet of my navbar with the dropdown and the arrow that is next to it. Hopefully it helps!

Just add a class with transform: rotateZ(180deg) to the caret. Should probably specify the default rotate to be 0, so it can be transitioned as well.


// Navbar Dropdown
$(".ctx-dropdown-toggle").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".dropdown-menu").slideToggle(600);
  $(".chevron-icon").toggleClass("rotated")
});
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600;700;800&display=swap");
@import url("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css");

/*navbar begin*/

.navbar {
  height: 60px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  --bs-navbar-brand-padding-y: 0px;
  --bs-navbar-brand-margin-end: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand-text {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red, magenta, magenta, lime);
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  background-size: 300% 100%;
  background-position: left center;
  transition: background 0.15s linear;
}

.navbar-brand:hover .navbar-brand-text {
  background-position: 100% center;
}

.navbar-brand:focus {
  outline: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

@media (max-width: 576px) {
  .navbar-brand>.navbar-brand-text {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 370px) {
  .navbar-brand {
    display: none;
  }
}

.navbar-toggler {
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  padding: 5px 10px !important;
  transition: border-color 0.15s linear !important;
}

.navbar-toggler:hover {
  border-color: #ff0000;
}

.navbar-toggler:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 3px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7) !important;
}

.nav-link {
  color: #808080;
  transition: color linear 0.15s;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  color: #ff00ff;
}

.nav-link:focus {
  color: #ff00ff;
}


/*navbar end*/


/*dropdown begin*/

.dropdown-menu {
  background: #111;
  --bs-dropdown-min-width: 100px;
  --bs-dropdown-border-radius: 10px;
  --bs-dropdown-border-width: 2px;
  --bs-dropdown-border-color: #ff0000;
}

.dropdown-menu a {
  color: #808080;
  transition: color linear 0.15s;
}

.dropdown-menu a:hover {
  color: #ff00ff;
  background-color: #111;
}

.dropdown-menu a:focus {
  color: #ff00ff;
  background-color: #111;
}

.dropdown-divider {
  border-top: 1px solid #252424;
}

.dropdown-item:active {
  background: #111 !important;
}

.dropdown-item:focus {
  background-color: #111;
  color: #ff00ff !important;
}

.bi-chevron-up {
  display: inline-block;
}


/*dropdown end*/

.chevron-icon {
  transform: rotateZ(0);
  transition: 150ms;
}

.chevron-icon.rotated {
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Cratex Studios</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.5.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-B4dIYHKNBt8Bc12p+WXckhzcICo0wtJAoU8YZTY5qE0Id1GSseTk6S+L3BlXeVIU" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico" />
  <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false">
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="navbar">
      <div class="container-fluid justify-content-between">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#leftMainNav" aria-controls="leftMainNav" aria-label="Toggle left navigation">
                        <i class="bi bi-list"></i>
                    </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
          <img style="width: 30px" src="assets/images/logo-l.png" />
          <span class="navbar-brand-text">Cratex Studios</span>
        </a>
        <div class="d-flex" style="width: 250px">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <a class="nav-link ctx-dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Company <i class="bi bi-chevron-up chevron-icon"></i
                                ></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu position-absolute" style="top: 55px; width: 110px">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/mission.php">Mission</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/partners.php">Partners</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/affiliates.php">Affiliates</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/legal.php">Legal Info</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/support.php">Support</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <hr class="dropdown-divider" />
                </li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item text-center" href="company/team.php">Our Team</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-menu mt-1 ms-2 me-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#signupModal">
                            Sign Up
                        </button>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#rightMainNav" aria-controls="rightMainNav" aria-label="Toggle right navigation">
                            <i class="bi bi-list"></i>
                        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end bg-dark" tabindex="-1" id="rightMainNav" aria-labelledby="rightMainNav">
          <div class="offcanvas-header">
            <button type="button" class="justify-content-end offcanvas-close-btn" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close">
                                <i class="bi bi-x-circle"></i>
                            </button>
            <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="rightMainNavLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="offcanvas-body justify-content-end">
            <ul class="navbar-nav text-end">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start bg-dark" tabindex="-1" id="leftMainNav" aria-labelledby="leftMainNav">
          <div class="offcanvas-header">
            <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="leftMainNavLabel">Offcanvas</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="offcanvas-body">
            <ul class="navbar-nav d-flex">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a type="button" class="btn d-inline-flex align-items-center border-0 nav-link" data-bs-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true" data-bs-target="#components-collapse" aria-controls="components-collapse">
                                        Components
                                    </a>
                <ul class="list-unstyled ps-3 collapse" id="components-collapse">
                  <li>
                    <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#accordion">Accordion</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#alerts">Alerts</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#badge">Badge</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#breadcrumb">Breadcrumb</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#buttons"
                                                >Buttons</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#button-group"
                                                >Button group</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#card">Card</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#carousel">Carousel</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#dropdowns"
                                                >Dropdowns</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#list-group"
                                                >List group</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#modal">Modal</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#navs">Navs</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#navbar">Navbar</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#pagination">Pagination</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#popovers"
                                                >Popovers</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#progress"
                                                >Progress</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#scrollspy"
                                                >Scrollspy</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#spinners"
                                                >Spinners</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#toasts">Toasts</a>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded text-decoration-none" href="#tooltips">Tooltips</a
                                            >
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>



